# ASP.NET.После релиза пропадают папки

Tags: c#, asp.net

Добрый вечер.Есть проект на asp.net mvc 5.Попробовал сделать релиз.В релиз-версии отсутствуют папки, которые были изначально

Содержимое папки Content изначально
[image: дебаг]

Содержимое папки Content в релизе

[image: релиз]

Comment: Вам надо добавить эти файлы в проект и указать, что эти файлы должны быть скопированы в выходную папку. Без этого сборщик, который собирает вам вебсайт, не поймет, что это нужные файлы, и их проигнорирует. Добавляете файлы в проект, нажимаете на файле правой кнопкой, там в свойствах выбираете тип Content, действие Copy Always

Comment: Если у вас сотни файлов и папок среди исходников и которые никак не компилируются, но которым обязательно надо заливаться в прод, то вам надо пересмотреть ваш подход к разработке. А пока все равно придется добавить их в проект как я описал выше.

Comment: @tym32167 поэтому я и хотел перейти в лс, чтобы не спамить тут, ну раз не получится, то напишу здесь. Папка Users предназначена для файлов, загружаемые пользователями(фотографии и т.п.). Под свойством я имею ввиду свойство "Копировать в выходной каталог". Даже не знаю как объяснить значение слов физический и виртуальный.

Comment: Те данные, что юзеры сохраняют, их не должно быть среди исходников вашего приложения - это данные, а не код. Тем более деплоить данные на прод из кода вообще практика так себе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73569/discussion-on-question-by---asp-net----).